# What are the assumptions of maximum likelihood estimation for a linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

I'd like to know the necessary assumptions of maximum likelihood estimation for a linear regression. Hope to hear some explanations.

Comment: See my answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149111/71364

Comment: Most importantly: independence.