# MSE of a regression obtianed from Least Squares

Tags: regression

Suppose you have some dataset $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ from some distribution $\mathcal{D}$ (if convenient to obtain a closed form formula, $\mathcal{D}$ can be a Gaussian distribution or something else that is tractable).

You posit a linear model, and you compute the least squares estimate $\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y.$

Can you say anything about the MSE of $\hat{\beta}$? Of course, I imagine that for a fixed $X$ this is difficult, but maybe you could compute the expectation of the the MSE of $\hat{\beta}$, where the randomness in this expectation is over the dataset $(X,y)$?

This feels like a standard enough problem so that I wanted to first ask if anyone knows about this or has any helpful references. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You haven't said what you want to take as the true value $\beta^*$ when defining the MSE; I'll take it as the value that minimises expected squared error for predicting $y$, which is the the thing that $\hat\beta$ estimates.

It's actually easier for a fixed $X$.  In that setting, $\hat\beta$ is a deterministic linear function of $y$ and is unbiased for $\beta^*$. By linearity its variance (and thus also its MSE) is
$$\mathrm{var}[\hat\beta] = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T \mathrm{var}[y] X(X^TX)^{-1}$$
where $\mathrm{var}[y]$ is the covariance matrix of $y$ (diagonal if the observations are independent -- you didn't specify).  This can be estimated by the 'sandwich' estimator
$$\widehat{\mathrm{var}}[y]= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T (X^T(y-X\hat\beta)(y-X\beta)^TX) X(X^TX)^{-1}$$

If $X$ is not fixed, you get to use the conditional variance formula
$$\mathrm{var}[\hat\beta]=\mathrm{var}[E[\hat\beta|X]]+E[\mathrm{var}[\hat\beta|X]]$$
where neither term is zero.  This is harder because the best 'true' $\beta$ depends on the configuration of $X$ (which is why the first term isn't zero).

Larry Wasserman's lecture notes [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=sml/LinearRegression.pdf) have some relevant bounds over distributions ${\cal D}$ with bounded support, including a bound for prediction MSE.

Comment: I think I might have been asking a slightly different question. I want to know the following: if $\hat{\beta}$ is computed, is there a way to analyze the population mean squared error (i.e., averaged over the distribution $\mathcal{D}(x,y)$) of $\hat{\beta}$? I think this is slightly different from the variance of $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: It's not different if $X$ is fixed; it is different if $X$ is random, though then you also have to think about what to do when $\hat\beta$ isn't defined, which has positive probability for any $n$ and any ${\cal D}$

Answer (score 4):

It is actually easier for a fixed $X$ than for ranging over $(X, y)$. The former case is more commonly analyzed, since it doesn't require you know the distribution of $X$.

The MSE of an estimator is [equal to its variance plus the square of its bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship).

[Under certain conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149111/302117), OLS is an unbiased estimator. The variance of OLS can be computed as such:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var} \, (\hat{\beta} \, | \, X) &= \operatorname{Var} \, ((X^TX)^{-1} X^{T}Y \, | \, X) \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1} X^T\operatorname{Var}(Y \, | \, X) X (X^TX)^{-1} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1} X^T\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon \, | \, X) X (X^TX)^{-1}
\end{align*}

If the errors are normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2$ then this reduces to:

\begin{align*}
\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}
\end{align*}

*Edit:* I answered at the same time as @Thomas Lumley. That answer completes the part where $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon \, | \, X)$ is unknown so we must estimate it.

Comment: I think I might have been asking a slightly different question. I want to know the following: if $\hat{\beta}$ is computed, is there a way to analyze the population mean squared error (i.e., averaged over the distribution $\mathcal{D}(x,y)$) of $\hat{\beta}$? I think this is slightly different from the variance of $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: The "MSE of $\hat{\beta}$" is defined as $E[(\hat{\beta} - \beta)^2]$. It sounds like you might be looking for some other metric like the "generalization error" in which case you need to update the question.