# Transforming input features for ANN

Tags: neural-networks, data-transformation, standardization

I usually normalise my input variables for linear models (i.e. apply a log transformation, or rank-based inverse normal transformation). One of the reasons I like using tree based methods like Random Forests and XGBoosts is that I do not need to transform the input features (when using these algorithms for classification).

I know that it is important to scale input features for neural networks (i.e. subtract values by the mean and divide by the standard deviation), but is there a need ensure input features are approximately normal when using neural networks for classification (like I would for linear models)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a need ensure input features are approximately normal when using neural networks for classification

No. And, this isn't required even for linear models. An answer related to linear regression is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148803/how-does-linear-regression-use-the-normal-distribution) thread.